# Recover external USB disk that was erased using Mac OS Disk Utility

Tags: mac, data-recovery

I need to recover data (very large video files) from an external USB disk that was accidentally formatted in Disk Utility on MAc OS.

Original Partition - EXT-DOS

Newly created partition - Mac OS Extended

Nothing was written to the disk, the mistake was realized immediately during the process.

I have scanned the drive using Disk Drill that finds the lost partition but the video files are not there, just some small jpg pictures that I could recover fine.

Is there a way to restore the previous file structure to find the large (10GB+) files or the sector by sector scanning the only option? I had trouble doing that in the past as the videos were recovered but corrupted.

[image]

I have looked at the other question, which is 11 years old and finding the tools and options mentioned obsolete: [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inaccessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: photorec is able to do file based recovery.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for - PhotoRec is the same as other tools, scanning the sectors of the storage. I am looking for something to "undo" the format action in order to restore the previous EXFAT partition.

Comment: In general there's no way to strictly undo this at home. The overwritten parts of the old filesystem (including some crucial structures) have been, well... overwritten; they no longer exist. Subtle traces may or may not be recoverable in a specialized laboratory due to hysteresis or something, depending on the type of the device. What you can do at home is to examine not-yet overwritten parts in a search for what looks like data with some known structure. This is what `photorec` does.

Comment: @TomEus You said you want to recover files from the drive, not to recover the partitions. That is a difference. In that case have a look at `testdisk`. Keep in mind that data recovery tools are able to destroy your data even further if handled wrong. I would advise to create a bit-by-bit copy of the whole drive with `dd` and only work on the image.

Comment: Realistically there's no 'undo'. There's recovery of files not yet overwritten.

Comment: The correct answer SHOULD go on the linked duplicate, but as OP notes, the duplicate despite being the correct duplicate does not address this case well or with current information.

Comment: FWIW I added an answer to wiki linked to that may address question: https://superuser.com/a/1758086/705502